# Filtering chloropleth data using a slider for annual data in vega-lite

Tags: geojson, vega-lite

I have some geojson grids that map through to some annualised sales data over a period of 25 years.  I am really struggling to filter this sales data by year to show the trends in a chloropleth map.

```json
    
    d3 = require('d3-dsv');
    map_json = FileAttachment("Time_line@2.geojson").json()
    sales_data = FileAttachment("Timeline_test@1.csv").csv()
    vegalite = require('@observablehq/vega-lite')

    vegalite ({
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 350,
      "data": {
        "name": "mapdata",
        "values": map_json,
        "format": {"property": "features"},
      },
      "params": [{ 
                    "name" : "AnnualPeriod", 
                    "value": 1995,
                    "bind" : {"input": "range", "min":1995, "max":2020,"step":1 }
                 }],
      "transform" : [{
                    "lookup": "properties.id",
                    "from": {
                      "data": { "values": sales_data,},
                      "format":"csv",
                      "key": "derived_boundary_id",
                      "fields": ["sales_volume"],
                    },
                  },],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "geoshape",
          "encoding": {
            "color": {
              "field": "sales_volume", 
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"scheme": "Oranges"},
            },
            "stroke": { "value": "#ff75"},
          },
        },
        ]
    })
```

I have tried to add transform.filter and cannot get it to work.  At the moment it appears to be taking the first sales_data record for each of the boundary_ids.

I would like the data to be filtered according to the setting of the AnnualPeriod slider.

I think I need to include something like

```
    "transform" :[{"filter": "datum.year == AnnualPeriod"}]
```

I have tried it in the transform section, with the lookup between the sales_data and the geojosn objects.
I have also tried to filter in and around the geoshape mark but neither work.
Does anyone have any ideas?

The is a sample of the sales_data:

```text
    sales_volume,year,derived_boundary_id
    5,2015,602212
    2,2016,602212
    2,2019,602212
    5,1995,602213
    7,1996,602213
    6,1997,602213
    7,1998,602213
    9,1999,602213
    10,2000,602213
    7,2001,602213
    5,2002,602213
    5,2003,602213
    9,2004,602213
    5,2005,602213
    ...
```

where the last column maps to an "id" in the geojson data.

and this is the 'map' that I get.  Always the same, irrespective of the slider setting.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have eventually worked out how to get this to work.

Create the main data source as the sales data and attach the maps/geojson to this via a transform/lookup.

It seems so simple now, but I thought I would post the result so others can see how it can be achieved.

These observations may help others:

1. The transform can take the "year" filter as well as the map_json lookup.
2. The map/json lookup is referenced as "geo" to make it easier to understand
3. The geoshape mark then references, via the encoding, this geojson "geo" object.

Thanks to Mike Bostock and the Observable and Vega-Lite team for their excellent work.

```json
    vegalite ({
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 600,
      "data": {
          "values": sales_data,
      },
      "params": [{ 
                    "name" : "AnnualPeriod", 
                    "value": 1995,
                    "bind" : {"input": "range", "min":1995, "max":2020,"step":1 }
                 }],
      "transform" : [
        {"filter" : "year(datum.year) === AnnualPeriod"},
        {
          "lookup": "derived_boundary_id",
          "from" : {
            "data": {
              "values": map_json,
              "format": {"property": "features"},
            },
            "key":"properties.id",
          },
          "as":"geo",
        }
      ], 
     
      "mark":"geoshape",
      "encoding": {
        "shape": {
          "field":"geo",
          "type":"geojson",
        },
        "color":{
          "field":"sales_volume",
          "type":"quantitative",
          "scale": { 
            "scheme":"Oranges",
            "domain": [0,15],
          },
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

How's your progress? I am not familiar with Choropleths, but by comparing with the [Vega Examples](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/#maps-geographic-displays), I spot 2 differences you may wanna take a look:

- Choropleth needs a [`projection`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/projection.html#projection-types)
- Map data should be placed in `lookup` transform, and sale data in normal `data`. [Ref 1](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_trellis.html) [Ref 2](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_repeat.html)

Do feel free to correct me if I am wrong. If you need more help, please share an editor with dummy data because I found it hard to make good use of the sale data you provided :'(

Comment: Thanks @hk7math.  I removed the projection elements to simplify the code I uploaded here and there is no difference, in behaviour,  from this to my 'real' working version.  I believe that if no projection is specified, then it defaults to WG84. I will read your references on point 2 but  I have tried it the other way around, but most of the examples I have found seem to determine that the 'map' data should be the main data source with the 'sales' data attached via lookups.  I will now read those references and report back.  Thanks for your observations.